# build mailer process with php

Tags: php, email, background-process, mailer

Hi
I want to create a mailer with php that will use a qeue of unsent emails and send them one by one. I know how to build the mailer itself, but I don't know how can i let it run in the background on the server-side. I don't want to execute the script with a browser, but maybe as a background process/exe/scheduled task (The server OS is windows).
Hope you understand my question, my english is terrible :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say cron, but because its a windows box I'll say "task scheduler".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569

Answer (score 0):

You can program it run at certain time with a cron job and wget commands on a linux server,

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `cron` jobs, use it, it's very useful for tasks running in the background. That's assuming you have `root` access on your server to add cron jobs of course.

```
# check for queued emails every 10 minutes "*/10"
*/10 * * * * php /path/to/your/cron.php
```

Read about it [here](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/schedule_tasks_on_linux_using_crontab). I hope that gives you an idea.

****UPDATE****

On windows, it's the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) which you also specify the file that you want schedule and time of execution.